# Unicode character 0x1 not being removed

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, unicode

I have the following code in order to remove ALL invalid Unicode characters before sending them in XML in a SOAP request.

```
const invalidUnicodeRemoved = inputText.replace(/[\u0000-\u001F]/gm, '');
```

However, I keep getting the following error sending the XML: `An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1) was found in the element content of the document.`. So basically it has not been removed (or at least not all of them).

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes

Comment: @randomir I don't understand why it is a duplicate from that question. Seems to be a different issue.

Comment: See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280762/404556). JavaScript has a problem with unicode ranges. Btw, are you running this in node.js or browser?

Comment: If it's in node.js (ES6), the solution is to use `u` modifier in regex.

Comment: In node.js. Seems that the issue with ranges was before ES6, right? I believe I am implementing it the way they recommend for ES6.

Comment: Have you tried adding `u` modifier, like this: `/[\u0000-\u001F]/gmu`?